# how to upload image to the cloud storage via app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I am using python with google app engine.
I would like to get image from the browser and upload it to cloud storage.

the form:

```
<form action="http://myappId.appspot.com/test/uploadImage" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="file" value='file'><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

my server side:

```
class uploadImageTOCloudStorage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        image = self.request.get("file")
        gcs_file=gcs.open(GCS_BUCKET_NAME+'testImage.png', 'w')
        gcs_file.write(image.encod('utf-8'))
        gcs_file.close()

        self.response.write("succeed !")
```

the file saved in the cloud storage, but the problem that I couldn't download it, I got this error:

```
The file could not be opened, it may be damaged or user a file format that preview doesn't recognize !
```

what should I do ?

I don't want to use blobstore, because `create_upload_url` will be active just for ten minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you do not have a proper `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for your form?

Comment: aaa yes that's right, do you know How could I get the image type(png,jpeg...) and size ?

Comment: Yes, using the Image api.  That is a new question

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question, and you really should make an effort to read the docs for the Images API.  It is as simple as:  
       
`image_bytes = image_from_form.read()`  
 `image = images.Image(image_bytes)`  
`content_type = image_from_form.content_type`  
`width = image.width`