# Upload image to google cloud store through a web page form python, google app engine, angularjs

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, upload, google-cloud-storage

**First let me say**,

*I think I've read every stack exchange post that seemed relevant to this topic*.*

**What I'm trying to do:**

1. I'm trying to allow certain users to send an image to google cloud storage through a form on my site..
2. *Another requirement* along with sending that image to the cloud storage,is, I need to create a model of that image in the datastore, with it's relevant attributes.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is because..

**Approaches I've read about:**

*There's a bunch of approaches for getting images to the cloud storage:*

- through the blobstore api
- through the python client for cloud storage: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#Python_About_the_client_library
- through rest api (I was considering a json approach)https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#simple

I've read a lot of conflicting information,

and I've read so much I can't keep it straight,

however,

**I think the resolution was:**

**For blobstore**:

1. The blobstore.uploadtocloudstoragethingmethod may or may not have a file upload limit size (no that's not the actual call or method name) 2. The blobstore method sounded like it's going to be phased out??

**For Jason API**:

"However, the client library includes App Engine optimizations, **so using the REST API** might require extra development time. Note: The App Engine development server supports the Cloud Storage Client. **It doesn't support the REST API**."

**For the client library**:

I don't know. It looks fine so far. Here is the method I'm thinking about using:

> "**cloudstorage.open(filename, mode='r', content_type=None,
> options=None,
> read_buffer_size=storage_api.ReadBuffer.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE,
> retry_params=None)**
>
> In read mode (r) opens the specified Cloud Storage
> object for read. In write mode w, if the specified file exists, it
> opens it for an overwrite (append is not supported). If the file
> doesn't exist, it is created in the specified bucket."

**The stuff I'm using**:

1. Google App Engine
2. Python (for handlers, models,etc)
3. angularjs and jquery (front end)
4. json sometimes (backend)
5. GAE boilerplate (don't ask)

**What I think I'm gonna do :**

1. Get the user's image:

So, I found this form which I tested. It does grab a file from your computer:

```
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"
method="post">
Files to upload: <br>    <input type="file" name="uploaded_files"    size="40">    <input type="submit" value="Send">
```

(No, I can't use the,  the php junk in the action. I took it from some place in the docs, but I tested it, it does grab a file, no it won't send, and it would be silly to expect it to)

2. Modify my current handler (which takes care of creating a model of the image in the datastore) to also use

this method:

> "**cloudstorage.open(filename, mode='r', content_type=None,
> options=None,
> read_buffer_size=storage_api.ReadBuffer.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE,
> retry_params=None)**
>
> In read mode (r) opens the specified Cloud Storage
> object for read. In write mode w, if the specified file exists, it
> opens it for an overwrite (append is not supported). If the file
> doesn't exist, it is created in the specified bucket."

**My Problems so far**

I don't know how that form works, and I don't know how to get the right information from this form to a handler, and what info that handler will need, so I can process it, create the model (I already know how to create the model in the data store, already doing so), and also send the image to the google cloud storage with this method:

> "**cloudstorage.open(filename, mode='r', content_type=None,
> options=None,
> read_buffer_size=storage_api.ReadBuffer.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE,
> retry_params=None)**
>
> In read mode (r) opens the specified Cloud Storage
> object for read. In write mode w, if the specified file exists, it
> opens it for an overwrite (append is not supported). If the file
> doesn't exist, it is created in the specified bucket."

Can anyone give me an example? I can't find any good relevant posts or docs on what to put in the form such that it will grab the file, grab the other form data that the user fills in, and then ends up sending the image to the google cloud storage.

--UPDATE-- :

So, right after posting this, I googled gcs.open, which led to this post:

[how to upload image to the cloud storage via app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019626/how-to-upload-image-to-the-cloud-storage-via-app-engine)

I believe this could do the trick as far as backend goes, I do have one question left.

To repaste the question:

> [image: from post above]

**Questions:**

1. I don't know what the image name will be, I'd like to use the the existing one, or perhaps a random one. Suggestions?
2. Where do I stick this: enctype="multipart/form-data" ?
3. will number 2. mess with my other form data? I need more info than just this image in the post request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your questions:**

1. *I don't know what the image name will be, I'd like to use the the
   existing one, or perhaps a random one. Suggestions?*

I don't think that really matters, just make sure to think about possible name clashes and what would happen then. I think this mostly depends on the needs of your application. You can always use a random filename and retain the actual filename in the datastore next to a reference to the Cloud Storage item.

2. *Where do I stick this: enctype="multipart/form-data" ?*

Enctype is a form attribute and so needs to be set on the form element in your HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/save" ... >
```

3. *will number 2. mess with my other form data? I need more info than
   just this image in the post request*

No it should not. Just add more form input fields and they will all be submitted with the form data.

Comment: 1. Thanks :) currently looking up ways to use uniques. Thinking about just generating a name then seeing if that file exists in gcs. That could waste queries though. 2. Thanks! I ended up using <form action="{{ url|safe }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> and it went well. 3. Haven't tried it yet, thanks for the info :)

Comment: True about the extra queries. What you could do (assuming you store other data in the datastore for the file), is use the datastore key as a filename. That's guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'd wonder about what kind of security risks that could introduce to the datastore, as it would be easy to expose the key name via the browser, but appending random data on top of that id could help? the could be decoded probably. Not sure.. I did another project that used uniques, but I don't remember the method I used off hand..

Comment: I don't think there would be a concern in exposing the datastore key, unless you are using a sensitive ID part of the key. However, I was thinking more that you could use the key to store it (ensuring uniqueness), but when retrieving it from Cloud Storage in order to send it to the user you'd rename the file with the original filename that you stored in the datastore.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would play out, as the cloud storage has the actual image, and the datamodel contains the path to that image. If those aren't the same, it wouldn't be possible to display an image to the user. I did find my old code though, would still involve queries to the datastore however, and uses a Unique class from webapp2 extras

Comment: I found this today, "You can also use an entity's key to obtain an encoded string suitable for embedding in a URL:url_string = sandy_key.urlsafe()" so that takes care of the security issue, or not: Note: The URL-safe string looks cryptic, but it is not encrypted! It can easily be decoded to recover the original entity's kind and identifier:

key = Key(urlsafe=url_string)
kind_string = key.kind()
ident = key.id()

Comment: The term "key" is slightly misleading. A key is nothing more than a unique identifier for an entity by combining the entity kind and the entity ID within that kind together. It doesn't give someone any kind of access to anything, so there's nothing wrong with someone having a key for an entity. Unless of course you don't want a user knowing the names of your models and the entity IDs they are stored under. This would be the case perhaps if you have a User model and use their email address as the ID part of the entity key. This would mean you get something like Key('User', 'joe@example.com').

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a signed form for a direct upload to GCS. This way you do not need the blobstore or a post handler. And you can control the timeout and objectname using a policy document. See my aswer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452720/direct-user-upload-to-gcs-with-given-name-and-parameters).

Comment: Not sure "signed form" means anything -- do you mean "signed *URL*", as per https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs ?

Comment: I thought "signed form" is more appropriate for this solution. Docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject